# jquery: h1 for body id="home", h4 for every other body id

Tags: jquery, html

Howdi all, I'm using a PHP include for my header section and I want to be able to have my logo wrapped in a h1 for the homepage, and a h4 for the rest of the pages. My homepage has a body ID of "home" and the rest of the pages have their own IDs as well. Is there an easy way to achieve this with jQuery? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your logo element has ID `#logo`.

To wrap on your home page, use a normal ID selector, and to wrap on every other page use a "attribute not equals selector":

```
$('body#home #logo').wrap('<h1>');
$('body[id!="home"] #logo').wrap('<h4>');
```

That said, the code that's producing your pages should be putting the right tags in the page in the first place!

Comment: Brilliant. Worked a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Seems you should be using a class on those H1/H4s, but if you must, try this:

```
$('body#home h1').css("background-image","url('/path/to/large/image.png')");
$('body[id!='home'] h4').css("background-image","url('/path/to/small/image.png')");
```

But I would suggest doing something like this instead:

```
<body id="home">
  <h1 class='logo'></h1>
</body>

<body id="another_page">
  <h4 class='logo'></h4>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
h1.logo { background-image: url('/path/to/large/image.png'); }
h4.logo { background-image: url('/path/to/small/image.png'); }
```

Comment: Good call with the Css option. "Don't do something with jQuery you can easily do with Css" I believe someone said.

Comment: Thanks. I would do it like this but because I am using one include file for all pages, it doesn't seem right...  <h1>logo</h1> then <h4>logo</h4> would be output on all the pages, and css would hide/show the right one. Just doesn't feel right... Actually, it's not right as I would want to use h1 for other areas in the internal pages...

Comment: If you are using a common header include file, that file should be dynamic, so you can change the HTML server-side. If you use a static header for pages that *do* need little header differences, you are going to regret it later on